# ActiveState Perl and Win32::OLE on Windows 10

Tags: perl, ole, sqloledb

I'm trying to figure out what some old Perl that is used for reporting on our websites is doing. I've gotten ActiveState Perl installed and things seem to be working EXCEPT that when the Perl tries to open a database connection. The following error is displayed:

```
Error creating ADODB.Connection to [our connection string redacted]: OLE exception from "ADODB.Connection":

Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.

Win32::OLE(0.1712) error 0x800a0e7a
    in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "Open"" failed:256
```

The offending line of Perl is:

```perl
$dbhandle = dbOpen(%dbConnectstr);
```

The following use statements are also used:

```perl
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects';
```

How do I install (or configure or?) the provider on Windows 10?

Comment: Is `dbOpen(%dbConnectstr)` a typo? Are you sure you didn't mean to write `dbOpen(\%dbConnectstr)` instead? Is `dpOpen()` your own code or from a module? If it is your own code, you should add to your question.

Comment: I don't recognize `dbOpen`. Is it a function they wrote? You may need [ADO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/microsoft-activex-data-objects-ado?view=sql-server-2017) installed or to mess with ODBC settings.